# PJSIP Call, Play Music and Hangup

Tags: python, protocols, sip, pjsip

I am new to PJSIP. I want to make an app that makes a call, plays wave file and hangs up after that. When I use the following code, Call is made but I cannot hear any music that is supposed to play (message.wav) on my mobile. Is there anything wrong with the code ? If so, what is the correct way to write the code for the play wav music in python. This is the complete code link https://github.com/jrocharodrigues/sipamos/blob/master/sipamos.py

```
def on_state(self):
    global current_call
    global in_call
    print "Call with", self.call.info().remote_uri,
    print "is", self.call.info().state_text,
    print "last code =", self.call.info().last_code, 
    print "(" + self.call.info().last_reason + ")"

    if self.call.info().state == pjsua.CallState.DISCONNECTED:
        current_call = None
        print 'Current call is', current_call

        in_call = False
    elif self.call.info().state == pjsua.CallState.CONFIRMED:
        #Call is Answred
        print "Call Answred"
        wfile = wave.open("message.wav")
        time = (1.0 * wfile.getnframes ()) / wfile.getframerate ()
        print str(time) + "ms"
        wfile.close()
        call_slot = self.call.info().conf_slot
        self.wav_player_id=pjsua.Lib.instance().create_player('message.wav',loop=False)
        self.wav_slot=pjsua.Lib.instance().player_get_slot(self.wav_player_id)
        pjsua.Lib.instance().conf_connect(self.wav_slot, call_slot)
        sleep(time)
        pjsua.Lib.instance().player_destroy(self.wav_player_id)
        self.call.hangup()
        in_call = False

# Notification when call's media state has changed.
def on_media_state(self):
    if self.call.info().media_state == pjsua.MediaState.ACTIVE:
        print "Media is now active"
    else:
        print "Media is inactive"
```